# SymPy sine and cosine grouping

Tags: sympy

I have this expression:

```
simplify(a*cos(x)+b*cos(x)+y*sin(x)+m*sin(x))
```

When I ask SymPy to evaluate it, it returns the same expression (without `simplify` of course). I'd like to group my expressions around `sin` and `cos`:

```
(a+b)*cos(x)+(y+m)*sin(x)
```

How can I instruct SymPy to favor grouping around `sin` and `cos` ? Note that this is a simplified example, *a,b,y,m* are constant (possibly rich) expressions, *x* is the only variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

collect is the function you are looking for:

```
expr = a*cos(x)+b*cos(x)+y*sin(x)+m*sin(x)
expr.collect(cos(x)).collect(sin(x))
```

Comment: Completely missed that one. It definitely works.